# Inconsistent select() bahavior for input when parent has user-select: none (chromium-based browsers)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, chromium, blink

On the gif, you can see input with consistent `select()` behavior (content selected on every click) and second input where every 2nd click fails to select anything

[image]

I have global styles historically added to the project

```
* {
  user-select: none;
}

input {
  user-select: text;
}
```

What I found - `user-select: none` set on the parent is breaking `select()` method for its children inputs.

> **[[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)]** 
>   `user-select: none`: The text of the element and its sub-elements is
>   not selectable.

I can't remove old styles because it might affect too many things (we have plans to revisit this but not now), so I tried to override `user-select` behavior but no luck with that when I set `.parent {user-select: auto;} .parent .input {user-select: text;}`

As JS workaround I'm setting timeout 200ms before `select()` that works but with ugly flickering.

How do I override those CSS props correctly? 
(For this example I wrapped broken input into `.buggy` so the other can remain normal. But this doesn't represent the project structure as it has dozens of wrappers above the input and each has `user-select: none`)

**Just found this is reproducible in `chromium-based` browsers - chrome / edge / opera**

```css
.buggy * {
  user-select: none;
}

.buggy input {
  margin-top: 10px;
  user-select: text;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' value='normal input' onclick='this.select()'/>
<div class='buggy'>
  <div>
    <input type='text' value='buggy input' onclick='this.select()'/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Must be os specific: can't repro on chrome 80 nor 82 on macOs.

Comment: @Kaiido reproduced on `MacOS Catalina 10.15.3 (19D76) - Chrome 80.0.3987.122 (64-bit)` / `Ubuntu 19.10 - Chrome 79.0.3945.88` / `Windows 10 - Edge 80`

Comment: @Kaiido also `MacOS Catalina 10.15.3 (19D76) - Opera 67.0.3575.53 (64-bit)`

Comment: oO Ok.. I can repro now, using the trackpad of my macbook to perform the click. Doing the same from an external mouse doesn't reproduce the bug...

Comment: Ok so it was because I'm slower to raise the mouseup needed for the *click*  event to fire. Calling `select()` in the *focus* event I can repro with all pointer devices.

Comment: _“I'm unable to remove old styles for now”_ - do you mean you _can’t_ do that, because then something else will break - or that you really were not _able_ to?

Comment: [Found this related bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=764316)

Comment: @CBroe updated question - I can't remove these styles because it affects too many things. we decided to stay with this bug if no workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a weird bug which I haven't yet investigated where it comes from.
It might warrant a bug report, but note I could repro from M50, which means it will probably not be considered high priority.

For the time being, you can workaround this by clearing the [document's Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) before calling the `select` method:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach( elem => {
  elem.onclick = (evt) => {
    getSelection().removeAllRanges(); // clear all selection
    elem.select();
  };
});
```

```css
.buggy * {
  user-select: none;
}

.buggy input {
  margin-top: 10px;
  user-select: text;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' value='normal input'/>
<div class='buggy'>
  <div>
    <input type='text' value='buggy input'/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: teriffic solution mate! the only problem - it uses `onclick` - all subsequent selections (e.g. select half of input instead of full) will mix with the retriggered `.select()`